# Two column layout taking full screen but allowing one column to expand

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I'm trying to create a somewhat complicated layout with two columns taking up the remaining height of their parent but where one of the two columns is able to exceed these bounds if its content requires it. (In my case, this is an image but I don't believe this matters).

Here's a picture of the desired result which I'm sure will explain much better what I'm looking after.

[image: At the top a container of unknown height, followed vertically by two columns. The right column takes up exactly the remaining height of the screen after the top container. The left column is larger than the remaining height so it expands past the screen. There is one final content below everything, which is pushed by the expanded left column accordingly.]

*Note: Here the red border represents the screen bounds (100vw x 100vh).*

Here's what I tried so far:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.top {
  background: orchid;
}

.columns {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.columns>* {
  flex: 1;
}

.left {
  background: lightgreen;
  /* Just make it larger than 100% */
  height: calc(100% + 25px);
}

.right {
  background: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    Top Content
  </div>
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="left">
      Left Column
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      Right Column
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="additional">
  Additional Content
</div>
```

As you can see, the "additional content" section isn't pushed properly. This is because the left column is overflowing but isn't technically affecting its parent. I believe that if it did, then the right column wouldn't be sized properly. So this seems like two conflicting conditions and I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: This is not an answer, but by looking at your code. why don't you use grid?

Comment: @Strywyr I'm not entirely sure how to get a row to be both "as tall as needed for its content" and "as tall as the remaining space to fit within 100vh" at the same time, which is what I need for the two columns. Flexbox seemed like a better fit for this?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is the result you are looking for, but give it a try and let me know.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height:max-content;
}

.top {
  background: orchid;
}

.columns {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.columns>* {
  flex: 1;
}

.left {
  background: lightgreen;
  /* Just make it larger than 100% */
  height: fit-content;
}

.right {
  background: cornflowerblue;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

First, the container is set to `max-content`, meaning that it will be as hight as the highes element inside it. Next, the right column is set to `max-height:100vh`, meaning that if your left column is not as high as `100vh`, your container will be affected by that right column. As soon as left column exceeds `100vh` mark of right column, the `height:fit-content` of left column makes its parent expand, leading to pushing the additional content properly while right column stays at `100vh`.

In this case, if left column does not have enough content, it will get smaller then right column, if this is not desired behaviour, change the left-column height as you desire, but always us height properties that are affected by content (or min/max).

Comment: Hey, that's definitely a step in the right direction. There's an issue with the right column however. In your solution, the right column does not expand to fill the remaining screen height when the left column is small. I can change the right column's "max-height" to "height" instead to achieve something close, but that makes it take 100vh which isn't the same as the remaining height—it completely ignores the top container.